# Do scriptures describe the effects of Brahmastra?

Tags: scripture, weapon, brahmastra, itihasa

Brahmastra is debated to be similar in nature to Atom/Nuclear bomb. But my question is, do scriptures describe the effects of Brahmastra?

Comment: Scientific speculation?

Comment: @Pandya no scriptural reference of the nature of  Brahmastra which prove of debunk this theory

Comment: I edited your question so it's less speculative.

Comment: @AnuragSingh I think you're misremembering what I said in the comment section of this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2945/36 I didn't say that a Brahmastra by itself causes rain to stop occurring.  I said that if a Brahmashirastra (equal to 4 Brahmastras) is hit by another Astra, for instance another Brahmashirastra, then their collision causes rain to stop occurring in that place for 12 years.  That is why Arjuna and Ashwatthama were both urged to withdraw the Brahmashirastras they had launched at each other.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan looks great

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yes, I saw it now. I completely misremembered your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Brahmastra (Sanskrit: ब्रह्‍मास्‍त्र, Brahmāstra)** was a weapon created by the creator Brahma, for the purpose of **upholding Dharma and Satya (truth).** When the Brahmastra was discharged, there was neither a counterattack nor a defense that could stop it, except by Brahmadanda, a stick also created by Brahma.

The two great ancient epics of India, **Ramayana** and **Mahabharata** explained about Brahmastra like below:

“It was a weapon, so powerful that it could destroy the earth
in an instant  A great soaring sound in smoke and flames 
And on its sits death…” — The **Ramayana**

“Dense arrows of flame, like a great shower, issued
forth upon creation, encompassing the enemy…
A thick gloom swiftly settled upon the Pandava hosts.
All points of the compass were lost in darkness.

Fierce wind began to blow upward, showering dust and gravel.
Birds croaked madly… the very elements seemed disturbed.
The earth  shook,  scorched  by the terrible violent heat of this weapon.
Elephants burst into flame and ran to and fro in a frenzy…
over a vast area, other animals crumpled to the ground and died.
From all  points  of  the compass  the  arrows  of  flame  rained
continuously and fiercely. — The **Mahabharata**

In Ahirbudhnya Samhita of the Pancharatra Agama volume 1 and ValmikiRamayana, both explained same Effects of Brahmastra.

**1) The nature of some astra-s - missiles**

There are some verses that depict the nature of these astra-s. A few of them are given under. Though we may not actually acquire a projectile power with these verses, they may at least detail what these missiles are. The source of these verses is untraceable, but they are said to be in puraaNaa-s, and Shiva informs Sage Narada, about the missiles as below:

**Brahmaastram**

> **vaantam vahni samaayuktam vyomahaalaa samanvitam |
>   meSha dvayam danta yutam haalaahalam ataH param |**
>
> **ghana aadyam vaayu puurvam ca danta yuktam athaanvitam |
>   saram R^ikSha poaryaayam bhaantam bhR^igu mataH param ||**
>
> **ambaram vaayu sa~NyuktaH ari mardanam apyutaH |
>   pradiiptam atha avaktavyam paramam ca padam tataH |**
>
> **tat ete pade prayoktavye gaayatryaa madhyamam tataH |
>   pada trayam prayoktavyam etat brahma astram iiritam ||**

"It contains air, fire and cosmic poison, two goat-like fangs, full of poison, weighty, emits air, contains mercury, fiery, sparkling, sky is filled with air, enemy-killing, greatly radiant and it is projected with three hymns, Gayatri at its centre, it is known as **Brahma-astra**

> "**Atharva Veda** has proved that mantras can change weather, bring rainfall, produce heat, change thoughts in human minds around us, control animals and birds etc"

**2) Ahirbudhnya Samhita of the Pancharatra Agama volume 1:**

> **phantam vahnisamayuktam vyoma halasamanvitam | mesadvayam dantayutam halahalamatah param || 34-5 ||**
>
> **ghanadyam vayupurvam ca dantayuktamathantimam | sarasam carksaparyayam bhantam bhrgumatahh param || 34-6 ||**
>
> **ambaram vayusamyuktamarimardanamapyatah |
>   pradIptamatha vaktavyam paramam ca padam tatah || 34-7 ||**
>
> **tatte pade prayoktavye gayatryaA madhyamam tatahH |
>   padatrayam prayoktavyametad brahmastramIritam || 34-8 ||**

“It contains air, fire and cosmic poison, two goat-like fangs, full of poison, weighty, emits air, contains mercury, fiery, sparkling, sky is filled with air, enemy killing greatly radiant and it is projected with three hymn, Gayatri at its centre, it is known as **brahmastra**”

Comment: I edited out the part of your post that was a question rather than an answer.  But a question was already asked on the subject you're interested in: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2942/36

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate it. But I have not see anything related to "Brahmastra used for destroy atmosphere on Mars" is it true?

Comment: No, I've never heard of a Brahmastra destroying the atmosphere on Mars.  You can post a question on that if you want.  (And in you question you should include a link for where you read about the Mars thing.)

Comment: Yeah sure, I can do that, but I know there is a Scientific explanation but I am not sure is it related to here or not? and I haven't found any Scriptures written explanation regarding Brahmastra destroyed the atmosphere on Mars.

Comment: Well, if you ask about what happened to Mars' atmosphere, that would be off-topic.  But asking whether someone ever launched a Brahmastra at Mars isn't off-topic.

Comment: @CR241 What is the source of this translation? Can you point these verses you quoted in sacred-texts.com translation?