# Source and location and authenticity of below mentioned verses about a weapon of Mahabaratha

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, weapon

There are a lot of posts on the internet claiming that nuclear weapons were mentioned in Mahabaratha and were used in war.

1) Please link to the verses which mention nuclear or similar weapons preferably in sacred-texts.com Mahabaratha translation

Note: This is mainly about the authenticity of the quoted text and it's source

2) Are the verses quoted below correct translations? Some claim they were wrong translations done after the nuclear weapons were dropped on Hiroshima and Nagasaki.

3) Please give the reference (verse of Mahabharata) to the following verses from [UFOs and nuclear weapons](http://www.sacred-texts.com/ufo/ourpast.htm)

4) What is the source of this translation. i.e; Which translation was this extract taken? Is this from a partial translation, suggesting it's a fake or wrong translation?

5) I want to know where the following verses are in this translation.
http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm

I basically want to know where the below quoted verses are (location) in Mahabaratha and their authenticity and their translation source

Note: Sacred-texts.com is said to contain original translation unlike the viral copy and paste translations which do not quote sources and make extraordinary claims without any evidence.

> Gurkha, flying a swift and powerful vimana hurled a single projectile
>   charged with the power of the Universe. An incandescent column of
>   smoke and flame, as bright as ten thousand suns, rose with all its
>   splendor.
>
> It was an unknown weapon, an iron thunderbolt, a gigantic messenger of
>   death, which reduced to ashes the entire race of the Vrishnis and the
>   Andhakas.
>
> The corpses were so burned as to be unrecognizable. Hair and nails
>   fell out; Pottery broke without apparent cause, and the birds turned
>   white.
>
> ...After a few hours all foodstuffs were infected... ...to escape from
>   this fire the soldiers threw themselves in streams to wash themselves
>   and their equipment."
>
> Dense arrows of flame, like a great shower, issued forth upon
>   creation, encompassing the enemy... A thick gloom swiftly settled upon
>   the Pandava hosts. All points of the compass were lost in darkness.
>   Fierce wind began to blow upward, showering dust and gravel.
>
> Birds croaked madly... the very elements seemed disturbed. The earth
>   shook, scorched by the terrible violent heat of this weapon. Elephants
>   burst into flame and ran to and fro in a frenzy... over a vast area,
>   other animals crumpled to the ground and died. From all points of the
>   compass the arrows of flame rained continuously and fiercely. "

This is another quote.

https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-incidents-of-nuclear-war-or-nuclear-weapons-used-in-ancient-India

> "A single projectile charged with all the power in the Universe…An
>   incandescent column of smoke and flame as bright as 10,000 suns, rose
>   in all its splendor…it was an unknown weapon, an iron thunderbolt, a
>   gigantic messenger of death which reduced to ashes an entire race.
>
> "The corpses were so burned as to be unrecognizable. Their hair and
>   nails fell out, pottery broke without any apparent cause, and the
>   birds turned white.
>
> "After a few hours, all foodstuffs were infected. To escape from this
>   fire, the soldiers threw themselves into the river."

Comment: Why only sacred-texts.com? and not other website? So you mean Ganguli's translation by any chance?

Comment: http://www.sacred-texts.com/ufo/ourpast.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do scriptures describe the effects of Brahmastra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18961/do-scriptures-describe-the-effects-of-brahmastra)

Comment: @Pandya That is not the original Mahabaratha. It's part of the mistranslations.

Sacred-texts.com most of the times contain original translation without completely false and fan fictional translations found on other sites

Comment: @Notty Yes, do you mean you want references from scripture e.g Mahabharata for the mentioned text? see my edit to the question

Comment: I'm especially concerned about the part that suggests an airplane dropped the bomb. I'm unable to find those parts in any original translations including those on sacred texts

Comment: @Pandya Yes, I want to know which are the verses so, I can find them in other translations and the sacred-texts.com translation