# Is Hanuman going to be future Brahma?

Tags: vedas, puranas, brahma, hanuman

I have read in multiple forums, which talks about Hanumana being rewarded as future Brahma.

Can anyone point out, where exactly it is mentioned that he is going to be future Brahma?

Comment: So far I haven't found anything, but in Swami Krishnananda's commentary on the Bhagavad Gita, he says this: http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/bgita/bgita_27.html "It is mentioned in the Valmiki Ramayana that the next Brahma will be Hanuman: svayam nava vyakaranarthavetta brahma bhavatyapi te prasadat."  But I couldn't find the verse in the Valmiki Ramayana, and I don't think the Valmiki Ramayana mentions Kalpas and successions of Brahma and so on.  Perhaps the quote is actually from some Purana.

Comment: Hanuman is the pure incarnation of Vayu. As well known in all puranas and other similar texts, it is mentioned that this creation's Vayu is next creation's Brahma. Since it is the process, Rama granted the boon of Brahma's position for Hanuman

Comment: @mukunda Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.  Like do you know what Puranas mentions that this Mahakalpa's Vayu will be the next Mahakalpa's Brahma?

Comment: @Mukunda - "The Vayu of this Kalpa will be Brahma of next kalpa" is the view of madhvas, the followers of madhvacharya. I am not sure that there are any such reference in Epics or puranas.

Comment: @Krishna, you can refer RamayaNa for this boon from God Rama what was granted/given to hanumantha.

Comment: @Mukunda- You are right. That Ramayana does refer to boon by Rama to hanuman to become next Brahma ..but, doesnt mean that Vayu of present kalpa becomes brahma of next kalpa, always. If, Lord Narayana wants he can make you also as next brahma. That is Lord's prerogative based on ones merit. There are many instances where Vayu has acted against Lord Vishnu. There no rule that Vayu always becomes next brahma. Annamacharya in one of his kirtana, When present chatumukha brahma is still alive, Lord Vishnu gives brahmas post to some one else. It is purely based on Vishnu's grace

Comment: @Krishna Where in the Ramayana does Rama grant a boon to Hanuman to become the next Brahma?  By the way, have you seen my question about Nappinnai, the lover of Krishna mentioned by the Alwars: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7800/36

Comment: @Keshav - You need to ask this question to Mukunda. I think, it might be there in Uttara khanda, not sure. Need to check.

Comment: @Krishna As far as I know, the only boon that Rama gives to Hanuman in the Uttara Kanda is the one described in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1988/36 "[Rama] said to Hanuman: "It is settled that thou shalt live forever, do thou, now observe thy promise. As long as my history shall run current in this world do thou at my command live happily." Being thus addressed by high-souled Raghava Hanuman attained to great delight and said: "As long as the sacred theme shall pass current in this world I shall live here carrying out thy commands.""

Comment: @Keshav- i agree with you. I too tried to glance through Valmiki Ramayana, but couldn't find the boon of Hanuman becoming next Brahma. May be Mukunda knows where and he should let us know.

Comment: @Krishna By the way, have you seen my question on Yamunacharya's Stotra Ratna? http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7826/36

Comment: Hanuman represents prana. That is why he is Chirnajivi and son of Maruti. Whoever evolves to become Brahma will be thru prana and Pranayam. Mastery of Pranayam will lead to 8 sisdhis and 9 nidhis. Probably that is why Hanuman will be Brahma.

Comment: If Hanuman is going to be next Brahma then who is going to be next Hanuman.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, as per some recensions<sup>**‡**</sup> of the Uttara Kāṇḍa of the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa,  Hanumāna is going to be the future Brahmā.

This is foretold to Śrī Rāma by Mahaṛṣi Agastya himself in Chapter 36 of the  Uttara Kāṇḍa:

> [श्रीमदुत्तरकाण्डे षट्त्रिंशः सर्गः](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A9%E0%A5%AC)
>
> सर्वासु विद्यासु तपोविधाने प्रस्पर्धते ऽयो हि गुरुं सुराणाम् ।
>  सोऽयं
> नवव्याकरणार्थवेत्ता **ब्रह्मा भविष्यत्यपि ते प्रसादात्** ।। ७.३६.४८ ।।
>
> > महर्षि अगस्त्य ने श्री राम से कहा -
> >
> > यह (अर्थात् हनुमान) समस्त विद्या और तपोविधान में सुरगुरु वृहस्पति की
> > टक्कर के हैं, और व्याकरण के जानने वाले हैं। **अब आपकी (अर्थात् श्री राम की) कृपा से यह ब्रह्मा
> > भी होंगे।**
> >
> > [चतुर्वेदी द्वारका प्रसाद शर्मा कृत हिन्दी अनुवाद]
>
> [Hindi Translation by 'Chaturvedi Dwarka Prasad Sharma'](https://archive.org/details/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SanskritTextWithHindiTranslation-DpSharma10/ShrimadValmikiRamayan-SktHindi-DpSharmaVol09-UttaraKandaPurvardh1927/page/n451/mode/2up):

> `English Translation of the above Hindi Translation by Self`
>
> Mahaṛṣi Agastya said to Śrī Rāma:
>
> > Hanumāna rivals the preceptor of devas (i.e., Brihaspati) himself, in
> > all branches of learning and austerities. He is well versed in 'the
> > Nine-Grammars' (i.e., [Nava-Vyākaraṇa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50530/17833)-Vettā'), and **by your grace he will become the next
> > Brahmā.**

Further, as pointed out by the user [Keshav Srinivasan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7311/is-hanuman-going-to-be-future-brahma#comment14869_7311), this same verse is quoted (and thus translated as such) by Swami Krishnananda of the Divine Life Society in his discourse on [Chapter 9](https://swami-krishnananda.org/bgita/bgita_27.html) of the Śrīmada Bhagavada Gītā.

#### Therefore, we conclude that as per the Uttara Kāṇḍa of the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa - Hanumāna is going to be the future Brahmā.

---

### ‡

The [Gita Press Gorakhpur](https://archive.org/details/shrimad-valmikiya-ramayan-part-2-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n727/mode/2up?view=theater), and so do [Hari Prasad Shastri](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424802.html), also, uses the same recension with the same verses as used by the translator Shri Dwarka Prasad Sharma as given above. Although both of them, contrary to the popular notion, translates the Brahmā part as implying that 'Hanumāna will command respect similar to god Brahmā (and not become Brahmā himself in the next kalpa)'.

Further, in some recensions like that used by, [MN Dutt](https://archive.org/details/Valmiki_Ramayana_English_Prose_Translation_7_volumes_by_Manmatha_Nath_Dutt_1891_to_1894/Valmiki%20Ramayana%20-%20MN%20Dutt%20-%20Volume%207%20-%20Uttara%20Kanda%201894/page/n149/mode/2up?view=theater) and [Bibek Debroy](https://archive.org/details/valmikiramayance/page/n1335/mode/2up?view=theater), the 'next Brahmā' verse seem to be completely absent or in the case of [the Hindu scriptures](https://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/itihaas/ramayana/valmiki-ramayana-text-with-translation/vol-iv/chapter-36/topic-1) website, the second part of verse 38 is replaced (or omitted completely) by this line as follows:-

> सर्वासु विद्यासु तपोविधाने प्रस्पर्धतेऽयं हि गुरुं सुराणाम्।
> **प्रवीविविक्षोरिव सागरस्य लोकान्दिधक्षोरिव पावकस्य।**
>  लोकक्षयेष्वेव यथान्तकस्य हनूमतः स्थास्यति कः पुरस्तात्।।४६।।

Answer (score 0):

I've a doubt. If there are 9 brahmas (ours is 7th currently) in this universe, then what about the fact that while vishnu exhales a thousand brahmas come into existence? We know that we can measure grains of sand in Ganga or raindrops when indradev rains, but we cannot know how many universes got created and destroyed. If only 9 brahmas will come into existence, does it mean that our universe life span is 900 brahma years? What about other universes?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).