# Ramayana and Mahabharata in immediate yuga or after 3 cycles

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, yuga

Please pardon me for creating this duplicate topic,

as I am confused with the answer already given on this topic

[Did the Mahabharata and the Ramayana happen in the current Yuga cycle in the current Manvantara?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/did-the-mahabharata-and-the-ramayana-happen-in-the-current-yuga-cycle-in-the-cur?rq=1)

Please help me out in understanding this, If you believe I am breaking the forum rules please close this topic.

So in the above topic it is mentioned that ramayana was in 24th treta yugam and then comes 24th Dwapara yugam ,but Mahabarata actually took place in 28th Dwapara yugam.

So this means that mahabharata actually took place after 3 cycles of  4 yugams ?

Also if this is true, was there ramayana repeated in the 28th cycle too ?

Please help in understanding this ?

Also what is the current yugam cycle going on (it is 28th in above answer means if ramayana was repeated in 28th we are immediate in ramayana-28,mahabharata-28 and kaliyuga-28)?

Comment: No, the Ramayana did not happen in the present Mahayuga, only in the 24th Mahayuga.  As far as I know, the only other time the Ramayana happened was in a previous Kalpa, which is described in the Padma Purana.  In any case, we're currently living in the Kali Yuga of the 28th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara, i.e. the Yuga right after the Yuga where the Mahabharata war happened.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I have one more doubt, what happens to the immortals like parshuram,hanuman at the end of kalpa, for example hanuman of previous kalpa, will they be mortal in reference to kalpa. ?

btw I have also seen comments relating present hanuman to brahma of next kalpa :)

Also if in any case kalpa are repeated same then one of present brahma might have been hanuman in previous kalpa.

Comment: @Friendy Well, in a regular Pralaya only the three worlds are destroyed in the Samvartaka fire, so any sages who manage to attain higher lokas get to survive, although sages in Maharloka have to go to Janaloka to escape the heat of the fire; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2876/36 In the Mahapralaya, on the other hand, all the Lokas up to Brahmaloka are completely destroyed; Brahma himself dies and attains Moksha along with the other inhabitants of Brahmaloka. So almost no one survives the Mahapralaya except for Muktas (liberated souls) in Vishnu's abode of Vaikuntha.

Comment: @Friendy As far as I know, the only one who may have survived a Mahapralaya without having attained Moksha earlier is the sage Markandeya, but I'm not sure about him; he may have only survived a Pralaya rather than a Mahapralaya.  In any case, Parashurama's access to higher Lokas were destroyed by Rama in their famous encounter, so I'm not sure if he'd be able to escape to a higher Loka when the Pralaya comes.  As far as Hanuman being reborn as the Brahma of the new Mahakalpa, I'm not sure whether it's true, but there's a question here about it: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7311/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

As per archaeological(deep water excavation by our own archeologist Mr. Srivnivasan and finding Lord Krishna's drowned Dwapara ), historian facts (proof of an inscription mentioned by a greek king converting to vaishavism mentioning that Lord Krishna was born 84 generations prior to his time) and scientific proofs of atomic warfare (using radioactive isotope tests in kurukshetra area), you are right that Mahabharata happened in recent past i.e, 5100+ years.

Coming to Ramayana there are 2 versions - one says that archaeological proof of the coral reefs in the ram setu and give a dating back to some 30000 years and other according to planetory software with the mentioning of stars & constellations position says just around 7000+ years.

Found an interesting blog content whilst searching where it says that there have been 27 generations after Rama till Mahabharata where the lineage of Kusha, who is Brihadbala gets killed by Abhimanyu. Since Mahabharata happend 5000+ years from now.Now giving a calculated guess of people living for almost 100 years with better health you can give an average life of 75 per generation and it comes to 7000+ years from now.

Hope this info helps.