# Will Hanuman be Brahma and create the universe?

Tags: brahma, hanuman

Which scripture states that Hanuman will be next Brahma? I recently watched Mahabali Hanuman in which Krishna says Hanuman will become Brahma and will create universe.

Comment: may be this question discuss here already : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7311/is-hanuman-going-to-be-future-brahma