# Was current Lord Brahma once Hanuman?

Tags: brahma, hanuman

It is said in the epics that same events repeat in same yuga. If so, then Hanuman is going to be the next Brahma. Now does it mean the current Brahma was once Hanuman? Was current sage Vyasa, Ashwatthama in previous Dwapara-yuga?

Comment: Current Sage Vyasa is Krishna Dwaipayana Veda Vyasa he is Incarnation of Shri hari Vishnu and Ashwatthama would be next Vyasa(Ashwatthama is Incarnation of Ishna(Shiva)). Bramha is changed after a period of Mahakalpa which consists of 1000 Kalpas

Comment: We do not know who was Brahma in His previous birth. But [Hanuman is said to be next Brahma](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7311/3500).