# Will Saraswati exist in the future?

Tags: hanuman, yuga, saraswati

As said in some puranas and in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7311/is-hanuman-going-to-be-future-brahma), Hanuman will become the next Bramha. Also, as we all know, Bramha's wife, or to be exact,*shakti*,is Saraswati. Now, the *shakti* provides power to their respective husbands. In Bramha's case, his *shakti* is very important as Saraswati provides the knowledge and creativity needed for creation.

However, since Hanuman is a bachelor,he would not marry Saraswati. Hence, will she still exist in the future?

Morever, without her, he would lack the knowledge and creativity needed for him to creation. Plus, he would not have power/energy without a *shakti* and may cease to exist to. Besides, even Mahadeva (greatest of the gods) requires his *shakti* to function. Thus will Hanuman be able to create the universe?

Comment: First of all, there is no authentic scripture that says this. Even if he becomes Brahma, Hanuman doesn't literally create new universes. Soul of Hanuman will manifest as Brahma after current Brahma getting Moksha. Like how Shiva- Shakti are one and same, Brahma- Saraswati are same and Saraswati will again born from his body. So, it' just Soul not physical body.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Even if Saraswati manifests,Hanuman will not marry her as he is Brahmachari,so there will be no point in creating her because,as a Tridevi,it is her duty to provide energy as Brahma's consort and facilitate the universe's creation.

Comment: Can't you read properly? Why will Hanuman take Brahmacharya  in next life? Soul doesn't know any Brahmacharya. Brahmacharya is practiced by Humans with Phyiscal body. Hanuman's soul will take the form of Brahma, which is nothing but consciousness. Saraswathi will be an inherent part of Him. Please don't confuse with physical body and Atma.

Answer (score 1):

Anjaneya is Shi Ranji vi till the end of this kali yuga. Therefore , there is a chance  of reborn again as Brahma in the next yuga if he takes another form, not as Anjaneya. Maybe another Anjaneya will be born in the next (coming) Thretha yuga
when Rama is again born.