# How do Brahma and Saraswati die?

Tags: gods, brahma, saraswati

Brahmadev has a lifespan of 100 years and after that he dies.

I have certain questions about his death.

1. How does he die?
2. What happens to his wife Devi Saraswati after death of Brahmdev?
3. If Brahmdev life span is 100 years then is it true for Devi Saraswati?
4. As there is new Brahmdev after 100 years likewise is there new Devi Saraswati.

Comment: **Lord Hanuman was offered the post of Brahma dev**. Are you sure that you read about post of Brahma dev to Hanuman? Because as per my knowledge, Hanuman got offer of post of king of heaven (Indra post) by saptarishi. Besides, Brahma Dev is really a post?

Comment: Strongly related: [When Brahma's day ends and a new day starts does the previous day repeat itself?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20415/1049) and [Is Hanuman going to be future Brahma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7311/1049). In mythology, *Brahma deva* might be a post. But in reality,, *Brahma deva* & the supreme *Brahaman* should not be treated as different, IMHO.

Comment: I heard that, Hiranyakashyapu did extremely great tapas of Brahma dev. Heaven started to burn with fire of his tapas. So all Gods went to Brahma with the request of grant boon to Hiranyakashapu, If he continues his tapas like that then he will get Brama padd. I heard it long ago but didn't get the meaning of this talk earlier. But now when I read post named as Brahma here then I am started to get clue of this talk now between Gods and Brahma. I am not sure if Hiranyakashpu was about to become Brahma or not But I heard it long ago. But m also not sure if Brahma is post.

Comment: @Rishabh Lord Hanuman was offered the post of Brahma dev. I'm sure I have read it some where. I tried to find out but could not find. as soon as i find it I will update the link

Comment: @iammilind Friend can u please tell me how it is related.

Comment: @Rishabh https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20149/10089. Lord Hanuman As brahma dev

Comment: There is no mention of Lord Hanuman becoming future Brrahma in any scripture as far as I know. The answer you linked in the above comment doesn't cite any reference.

Comment: @Sinister I have not received ans for my 1st & 5th question. The link mentioned answer 3rd and 4th question.

Comment: The Qn is reasonably deviated, hence making comments & linked duplicate as invalid. It's better to restore the edits back and ask a new Qn. Refer [Update a question or post a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106249/163449).

Comment: I'm edited out parts of your question that are duplicative of other questions, and now I'm reopening it.  If you want you can post a separate question on how long the gap is between the death of the old Brahma and the birth of a new Brahma, to avoid making this question too broad.

Comment: Do you want the answer from "mythology" perspective or "philosophy" perspective? For example, "Krishna at 7 years winning over Kaliya snake" is mythology. "Krishna at 7 years bringing Kundalini (snake like tantra) in control" is philosophy. Interpreting Brahma deva as all other deva-s is mythology. But interpreted as BrahM is philosophy.

Comment: @iammilind I would like to have ans from both perspective.

Comment: @iammilind I am waiting for an answer

Comment: Actually your Qn is good. But then my answer will be from pure "philosophy" perspective. Just to be cautious, you may not find impersonal "Brahmaa" and "Sarswati". :-) I will try to compose and put it here after sometime.

Comment: @iammilind answer please. I'm eagerly waiting.

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad, I am preparing the answer for a while. Will post it soon as it will be quite long. Trying to make it concise. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @iammilind I thought you forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Long answer, as this is from the pure philosophical POV. For some of the contents, I have the verses and for some of them it's inferred. Refer below as a pre-requisite:

[Are there any scriptural references of the trinity “Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesh(Shiva)” as depicted in popular culture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21205/1049)

> > *3. "If Brahmdev life span is 100 years then is it true for Devi Saraswati?"*

**Lifespan is only a Day** for Brahma. Or **1 iteration** to be precise.
(Day = morning + night)

For self similar patterns, we may use term "cycle". But for not so similar repetitive patterns, I will use word "iteration". e.g. my previous birth and this birth are different. So I will call it 2 iterations of "iammilind" and not 2 cycles.

I interpret "BrahmA" (or Brahma-deva) from philosophical POV, as *Saguna Brahman* (whole universe). Universe as a whole can have only 1 iteration.

Now like you & me, if we consider the whole universe or *saguna Brahman* as a "being" / *Purusha*, then it dwells in ***nitya sattva*** (continuous illumination). This term is used in BG 2.45.

As the *sattva* increases the longevity increases. And hence, the time between the beginning & liberation decreases. For example,

- The time between beginning & end of Universe is only 1 cycle. The *sattva* is at highest. This 1 cycle is referred as 1 day of Brahman. In this case, 1 cycle will be same as 1 iteration of universe life:
  `1 human Kalpa (thousands of Yuga-1) = 1 day of Brahma`
- The time between beginning & end of stars/suns would be more than 1 iteration; These are called supreme of deities (*Surya deva* etc.)
  `Centuries of human Yuga-s = 1 day of Sun`
- The life time of earth like planets (*Bhumi devi*) is lesser than Sun etc. and hence it takes few more iterations compared to stars
  `Several human Yuga-s = 1 day of earth`
- Life times of various natural elements like rivers, land, wind, seasons etc. is now divided in even more iterations; However these are still divine compared to humans due to its *sattva* nature;
  `1 human year = 1 divine day`
- Life times of *pitru* are many more iterations;
  `1 human month = 1 ancestor month`
- Life times of humans and equivalent animals is average. Hence they have iterations in form of several Yuga-s compared to Brahma
  `1 human day = 1 human day`
- Life times of some reptiles & other animals are even less; Hence they would be finishing even more cycles; *Tamas* (ignorance) beginning to show up, from here predominantly
  `1 human decade = lifetime of animals`
- Life times of other small insects are lesser than these smaller animals; They take millions of iterations till Moksha
  `1 human week = lifetime of these insects`
- Life times of bacteria & virus are fractions of seconds and hence they would be finishing huge number of iterations.
  `1 human second = lifetime of insects`

Some of the [scriptural sources](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16085/1049).

Note that at top and at bottom of this list, it's "Me" or true "Self", where there is "no time". i.e. already in the state of Moksha.

> > *2. "What happens to his wife Devi Saraswati after death of Brahmdev?"*

The *Saraswati* here is a symbol of "Knowledge" or illumination. Knowledge of Brahman (or Self) is revered throughout Bhagavad Gita, so not quoting them here.

```
Knowledge of Supreme = Saraswati-Brahma
```

At the end of Brahma's morning. Everything merges back to the nature of the "Self/Me". Hence there is neither ignorance nor Knowledge. No space, no time. It's pure nothingness. So Saraswati merges back to Brahma and meets the same end.

> > *1. "How does he die?"*

"Die" is probably a wrong word. "Brahma" is Not a person or body. Here we refer it as a whole universe's consciousness (*Dehi*). The bacteria and cells on our body, has their own consciousness. But our body has a whole, its own consciousness. Similarly, the whole universe, which I called above as *Saguna Brahman* has it's singular consciousness.

> BG 2.30 - O descendant of Bharata, this embodied Self (देही)  existing in everyone's body can never be killed. Therefore you ought not to grieve for all (these) beings.

At the end of the morning (or day), the consciousness merges back to the self. For the living beings, it may appear like a *Pralaya*.

> BG 9.7 — O son of Kunti, all elementary entities enter My nature at end of the cycle(Kalpa); Again I create them at the beginning of the cycle.

---

> > *4. "As there is new Brahmdev after 100 years likewise is there new Devi Saraswati."*

Exactly same universe (*BrahmA*) and its knowledge source (*Saraswati*) would be born. No memory of previous cycle to retain the same similar pattern. Exactly same events and exactly same end. This is called *Kaala chakra* (Eternal Return). Please refer below post:

[When Brahma's day ends and a new day starts does the previous day repeat itself?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20415/1049)

<sub>Note: IMK, many people don't agree to this concept. Please use your conscience before subscribing to above philosophy.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

The age of Brahma is just a fiction of the Vaishnava agamas which in order to increase the importance of Vishnu consider Shiva and Brahma to be mortals while Vishnu to be immortal. I reality Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva are all manifestations of the same Parabrahmam and hence immortals and do not have a beginning or end, though they become latent, dormant or manifest according to the needs of the creation. Hence all three forms of Parashakti (Parvati, Lakshmi and Saraswathi) are Sada Suhagans or Nitya Saubhagyavatis.