# What are the नव व्याकरण​ ( Nava Vyakaranas )?

Tags: vedanga, panini, sutra

Hanuman is known as Nava-Vyakarana-Pandita (master of 9 grammars). What are these 9 vyakaranas ?

Vyakarana is one of the 6 Vedangas.

We know the famous : Maheshvara Sutras -> Panini Ashtadhyayi -> Patanjali Mahabhashya

Sanskrit is not a man-made language. They are eternal sounds of creation i.e Vedas. Their grammar was codified in certain sutras by Panini Maharaj, who himself mentions that he is not the first to codify a grammar (nor will he be the last).

Does it mean that there are 9 different grammars for Sanskrit, or 9 different ways of codifying the one grammar for Sanskrit ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one, as per [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=MsDtDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT460&lpg=PT460&dq=nava%20vy%C4%81kara%E1%B9%87a&source=bl&ots=YymfICaMQw&sig=ACfU3U1Xge5HZnpKzzOc_5ZGQOaMjaMq_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq9LOF1oj2AhXsRmwGHZyHBDI4UBDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=nava%20vy%C4%81kara%E1%B9%87a&f=false) -

> [image]
>
> **Aindiram** - said to be authored by Indra-deva himself.

---

### Edit:

Finally got a verse from the Sanskrit-Wiki-Website's page on the grammar Treatises ([vyākaraṇagranthāḥ](https://sa.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%83)).

> पुरातनाः व्याकरणग्रन्था
>
> यथा च श्रूयन्तेऽत्र प्राचीनानि व्याकरणानि -
>
> "**ऐन्द्रं चान्द्रं काशकृत्स्नं कौमारं शाकटायनम् ।**
>  **सारस्वतं
> चापिशलं शाकलं पाणिनीयकम् ॥**"
>
> > Now listen about the nine ancient grammars viz. the "nava-vyākaraṇa"
> >
> > 1. **Aindraṃ** (authored by Indra-deva)
> > 2. **Cāndraṃ** (authored by Candra-deva)
> > 3. **Kāśakṛtsnaṃ** - (authored by ācārya [Kāśakṛtsna](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kashakritsna)) - mentioned by  in the Mahābhāṣyam.
> > 4. **Kaumāraṃ** - (authored by Śarvavarman via inspiration from Kumara Kārtikeya) - [komāravyākaraṇa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kaumara), an alternative name of the Kātantra Vyākaraṇa. Said to be slightly available in the Agni Purāṇa.
> > 5. **Śākaṭāyanam** - (authored by ācārya [Śākaṭāyana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/shakatayana))
> > 6. **Sārasvataṃ** - (said to be authored by an ancient grammarian named Narendra via inspiration from goddess Sarasvatī) - [sārasvatavyākaraṇa](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/sarasvata)
> > 7. **Āpiśalaṃ** - (authored by ācārya [Āpiśali](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/apishali)) - also known as the  [āpiśalaṃ puṣkaraṇam](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/pushkarana).
> > 8. **Śākalaṃ** - (authored by maharṣi Śākalya) - also called the [Śākala](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/shakala) Vyākaraṇa
> > 9. **Pāṇinīyakam** - (authored by Pāṇinī ) - the famous Aṣṭādhyāyī sūtras.

The site traces these verses to [Śrītattvanidhi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sritattvanidhi) - a 19th CE treatise on iconography and iconometry. I have supplemented some information on each grammar from the Wiki-site's Sanskrit (as much as I could understand), and from the Wisdomlib and other sources.

By the way, Hanumāna being referred to as the 'navavyākaraṇa-vettā' (and the future Brahmā) maybe found in the Uttara Kāṇḍa of the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, Verse 7.36.48, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50579/17833).