# Who was Brahma before the Brahma we have now? Who will be the next Brahma(Hanuman ji?)

Tags: brahman, brahma

Brahma is a post and not a person. So who was the Braham earlier and will Hanuman ji be the next Brahma?
After how long would he be the next Brahma?

Answer (score 1):

> ***Brahma is a post and not a person.***

Well, If Lord Brahma is not a deity and just a post then you can find many such statements about Vishnu, Rudra, etc also scriptures. To name some example.:

Sri Shiva Purana 2.2.2.31.:

> 22. Satī is the beloved of Śiva by meditating upon whose lotus-like feet for ever and **by worshipping which Viṣṇu attained his Viṣṇu-hood.**
> 23. Satī is the beloved of Śiva, by meditating upon whose lotus-like feet for ever and **by worshipping which, Brahmā attained his Brahmā-hood.**
> 24. Śiva is the lord, by meditating upon whose lotuslike feet for ever and **by worshipping which the guardians of quarters—Indra and others attained their respective positions.**

Sri Shiva Purana 7.2.33.7.:

> kings, Siddhas, Yakṣas and Gandharvas, Rākṣasas, Bhūtas and Pisacas, besides other acheived their respective positions by adoring Śiva. All the gods achieved god-hoods, with the same process. **Brahma achieved Brahmattva, Visņu achieved the position of Vişņu, Rudra got Rudratva, and Indra got the position of Indra. Gaṇeśa was bestowed Gaṇeśahood with the same process.** Bathing Siva-linga with the white sandal paste it should be adored with the white lotus flowers. The salutation should be offered thereafter.

Mahābhārat — Anūśāsan Parva- Chapter —18 , Verse-64.:

> **Vasudeva said., "...If Rudra be gratified with a person, he can confer upon him the states of eIther Brahma or of Kesava or of Sakra with all the deities under him, or the sovereignty of the three worlds.**

Sri Bhavisya Purana 2.1.10.:

> 51-56. Planting only two Dhataki trees from thousands of mango trees is said to be the best, similarly one Patal tree is said to be the best from thousands of Pataki. One Raktabat from hundreds of Patals, five trees of Nagkeshar from two thousand Badhi, Shrivriksha and Jamun trees are said to be better than that, and three Tendu, five Jamun, Kadamba Arjun and three coconut trees are said to be the best. They must be planted, what kind of strength that pious soul gets by planting such trees, (I am telling). By planting these many types of trees, he gets the enjoyment of heaven for a thousand crores of kalpas, and a hundred crores of kalpas. The sins of the three births are destroyed and heaven is attained soon, **so by planting hundred trees, one has been told to attain Brahmahood and thousand to attain Vishnuhood respectively.**

Atharvashika Upanishad 2:1.:

> “The pranava (the sound of Om) makes all the souls to bow before it. It is the one and only one which has to be meditated upon as the four Vedas and the birth place of all devas. **One who meditates like that goes away from all sorrows and fears and gets the power to protect all others who approach him. It is because of this meditation only that Lord Vishnu who is spread every where, wins over all others. It is because Lord Brahma controlled all his organs and meditated upon it, he attained the position of the creator. Even Lord Vishnu , parks his mind in the sound (Om) of the place of Paramathma (ultimate soul) and meditates upon Îsâna. , who is most proper to be worshipped.** All this is only proper in case of Îsâna. ”.

So, By this logic, every Saguna deity is a Post.

> ***So who was the Braham earlier.***

Sri Skanda Purana 7.1.7.10.:

> Lord Shiva Said -
>
> 18. **When the sixth one well-known (by the name) Hemagarbha became Brahmā,** the Lord was glorified as Bhairavanātha.
> 19. **The present Brahmā is remembered as Śatānanda** and the name of the Lord now is Somanātha.
> 20. **Hereafter when the future Brahmā will be known as Caturvaktra,** the name of the Lord shall be Prāṇanātha.

Sri Skanda Purana mentions the name of the 6 previous Brahmas, the present and the future one also. The names are as follows.: Viriñci, Padmabhū, Svayaṃbhū, Parameṣṭhin, Hemagarbha (Hiranyagarbha), Śatānanda and the future one will be Caturvaktra.

> ***will Hanuman ji be the next Brahma? After how long would he be the next Brahma?***

As mentioned [in this answer.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50579/20968)

Uttara Kāṇḍa, chapter 36.:

> Mahaṛṣi Agastya said to Śrī Rāma:
>
> Hanumāna rivals the preceptor of devas (i.e., Brihaspati) himself, in all branches of learning and austerities. He is well versed in 'the Nine-Grammars' (i.e., Nava-Vyākaraṇa-Vettā'), and **by your grace he will become the next Brahmā.**

So, Lord Hanuman will become Next Lord Brahma and life time of a Brahma is 1 Maha Kalpa.

- **But, some Contradictions.:**

1. Skanda Purana already mentions, the Next Brahma will be Chaturvaktra then How Hanuman can be next Brahma.?

-> Well, some can say that, Chatur Vaktra means the 4 faced one. So, Hanuman will have 3 more faces. As, he already gave 5 face in his Pancha Mukhi form.

2. But, Mahabharata clearly mentions that all the 6 previous Brahmas are actually the same Brahma reborning again and again then the 8th Beahma should also be the same Brahma then how.?

The Mahabharata, Book 12.: Santi Parva.: Section CCCXLVIII.:

> **As regards myself (Brahma), I have sprung through thy (Narayana's) Grace. From thee have I derived my birth. My first birth from thee, which is regarded sacred by all regenerate persons, was due to a fiat of thy Mind. My second birth in days of yore was from thy eyes. Through thy Grace, my third birth was from thy speech. My fourth birth. O puissant Lord, was from thy ears. My fifth birth, excellent in all respects, was from thy nose. O Lord, My sixth birth was, through thee, from an egg. This is my seventh birth. It has occurred, O Lord, within this Lotus, and it is meant to stimulate the intellect and desires of all the beings. At each Creation I take birth from thee as thy son, O thou that art divested of the three attributes. Indeed, O lotus-eyed one, I take birth as thy eldest son, made up of Sattwa the foremost of three attributes.**

So, from the above verse it's totally clear that it's the same Lord Brahma only who reappears again and again.

Then, What about Lord Hanuman.?

Sri Shiva Gita Chapter 11.:

> 21-26.: Subsequently based on the Karma of the Jiva, female, male or eunuch bodies are obtained. Now I would explain the path of reaching higher abodes (gati) for the Jiva. Listen! One who possesses peaceful nature etc. good qualities , remains inclined towards the scriptures and righteousness, he is taken away till Brahma loka in celestial plane. With divine splendor, he becomes Devapurusha, and stays during Suklapaksham, Uttarayanam. **First attains to the abodes of Sun and moon, then atains to Vidyullokam, after that a celestial deity comes descends from Brahma loka to Vidyulloka (IndraLoka) and takes the Jiva to Brahma loka.In the abode of Brahma with the celestial body the Jiva enjoys all his desires for a long time. After staying there for a long period he gets moksha along with Brahma (viz gets absorbed into Sadā Siva by getting Kaivalyam Moksham).**
>
> 27-29.:Only that Brahmajnani remains one with Brahman as like as salt melts in water. As like as one can recall the dreams after waking up, a Brahmajnani also can recall everything similarly. For a Jiva who is devoid of Vidya (wisdom) and Karma third place is given which is Hell. Such a Jiva experiences extreme torture in Hells named raurava and similar ones and with the leftover Karma he gains birth as a heinous creature like flies, mosquitoes etc. on earth. this is about the Jiva Gati topic.

Conclusion.: So, basically what happens is that due to their Karma they goes to different different lokas having the same form of that deity (Swarupa Moksha same as Mahabali will be next Indra) and atlast goes to Brahma Loka and stays there till 1 Maha Kalpa and then gets Moksha. While the original Lord Brahma restarts his next cycle as 8th, 9th, etc Brahma.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: I am unable to trace the Matsyapurara quote. Would you mind sharing a link for the said verse?

Comment: I fixed the Reference. Actually, it's from Shiva Purana 7.2.33.7.

Comment: *have..........