# Is Lord Hanuman really immortal and what are ways to become his true follower

Tags: hanuman

The question just hit my mind with a question mark. Does lord hanuman really exists (immortal)?

What are the best ways to become his true follower and how to impress him.

Comment: For first part see this [Who made lord Hanuman immortal?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1976/3500)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our scriptures Lord Hanuman is mentioned as "Chiranjeevi" meaning "one who lives for ever".So, why being a believer of Sanatana Dharma ,will you doubt the scriptures,in the first place?

Even if you worship no Gods ,you can still get the blessings of all of them simply by following a righteous path of living as laid down in our scriptures.If you follow Dharma all Gods will be more than happy with you.And that includes Lord Hanuman too.

Some specific points relevant to Sri Hanuman:
1)Tuesday ,saturday are usually the days dedicated to him.Devotees usually(who can manage)fast on those days.You can also donate sindoor in Hanuman temples.Feed monkeys with gram dal and jaggery.
2)Read the Hanuman Chalisa.
3)Lord Hanuman is the greatest devotee of Lord Rama.So if you are devoted towards Sri Rama ,Sri Hanuman is already very pleased with you.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: That Sri Hanuman is Chiranjeevi is a fact mentioned in the Ramayana and he was so blessed by Goddess Sita.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he is immortal since he's Lord Shiva who is one of the Trinity. You can worship him by following his way. If you are a Vaishnavite (who believes Vishnu as the Supreme Being/God) , you can believe him as a follower/bhakt (Hindi:bhagat) of Lord Ram. But if you're a Shaivite (who believes Shiva as Supreme Being) you may worship him as God, since he is an incarnation of Shiva. I'm a devotee of Shiva, so I also read Hanuman Chalisa. If you want to be his true follower, you should believe him as the Supreme Being or Shiva (both are same).