# It is said that Lord Hanuman still lives on the earth, If it so where does he live?

Tags: hanuman

I have heard a lot that Lord Hanuman is immortal but I want to know where he lives?

Comment: he is living in my heart :-)

Comment: @Ajay No he is not living there. I am sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who made Lord Hanuman immortal?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/1976/who-made-lord-hanuman-immortal)

Comment: He must be living in some caves in the Himalayas.

Comment: @Rickross what is the significance of this staying on earth? doing nothing ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi You are asking as if i am his PA..anyways obviously he is doing what he is supposed to do. I will tell u short true story that happened with my first Guru Mother. " Once my Guruji was going out of station and he said to Hanumanji to take care of Guru mother. After that Guruji left Calcutta. And, thereafter, wherever Guru Ma went, be it her kitchen or  the marketplace she felt that some white colored being is always following him.. White colored since all body hairs have turned white..So Hanumaji is obviously doing what he is supposed to do i.e protecting his devotees.

Comment: Hanuman is Vayu avatar if you read brindhranyaka uphanishad.. he is the entity which holds your body together withoug falling apart similar to thread which holds the bead, the same holds good for the brahmanda.. he is abhimani devatha for chita.. @RakeshJoshi i think you need to learn vayu stuti .. mathar may mathrishwan  pitar athula guru swamin sarvaantharathman ..

Comment: Locals at Rameshwaram believe that God Hanuman still resides there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes Lord Hanuman is still on this planet. [Shrimad Bhagvat Puran Canto 5 Chapter 19](http://www.srimadbhagavatam.org/canto5/chapter19.html) mentions that he lives in the **Kimpurush Varsha** listening to Ramayan being sung by the denizens of the place and himself joining them in
the singing:

> किंपुरुषे वर्षे भगवन्तमादिपुरुषं
>   लक्ष्मणाग्रजं सीताभिरामं रामं तच्चरणसंनिकर्षाभिरतः परमभागवतो- हनुमान् सह किंपुरुषैः
>   अविरतभक्तिरुपासते ।
>
> आर्ष्टिषेणेन सह गन्दर्वैरनुगीयमानं
>   परमकल्याणीं भर्तृभगवत्कथां समुपशृणोति  स्वयं चेदं गायति ॥

**English Translation:**

> 1. S'rî S'uka said: **'In the land of Kimpurusha** the supreme and greatest devotee **Hanumân** delighting in service at His feet is together with the people always engaged there in worship of the Supreme Lord Râmacandra, the Original Personality who as the elder brother of Lakshmana is so 
>      pleasing to Sîtâ.
> 2. Together with Ârshthishena [the leader of Kimpurusha] attentively listening to the stories about his most auspicious master and Lordship being chanted by a company of Gandharvas, **he [Hanumân] himself** prays thus.

Coming to the **location of Kimpurush Varsha**, it is stated to be situated [north of the Himalayas](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/1/16/12) which could refer to the northern range of the mountains since Mansarovar Lake is also associated with it.

[image]

Comment: So we can go & see him there?

Comment: @Rohit. Can you go and see Shiva on Kailash? In this kind of Holly place humans are forbidden. They can visit that place only after death. Coz it is divine rule that Human can't meet Lord with their body made by panch tatva until they don't do Tapas. Since Hanuman also a Lord now, worshiped by world so you can't see him.

Comment: @Rohit. well no harm in trying :) I myself wanna do Kailash Yatra sometime and would definitely keep an eye out for him whenever I do!

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal :-) Great to know.

Comment: @Rishabh Oh. I see, Gods are enjoying stardom.

Comment: @Rohit. Stardom....? Well why not, After all they are real ultra mega super duper star of world. The things that they have done to the world, you can't do even in ur imagination, They live whole life for others. Always did help to the world. What you have done for this world except making baseless comments?

Answer (score 0):

Hanuman is a son of Vayu.
According to Valmiki Ramayana he lived in Kishkinda the capitol of the Apes which were called "Kimpurushas" in Srimad Bhagavatam 11.16.29 and are according to Mahabharata 1.66.8 offspring of Pulaha. Therefore Kimpurusha Varsha seems to be identical with Kishkinda which was located in a hole in the Himalayas.
It is said that Hanuman would live as long as the story of Rama (the Ramayana) is told (Valmiki Ramayana 7, 50 + 121; Mahabharata 3.291.44 + 48 f.).
According to Mahabharata 3.149.7 ff + 38 he has to change his shape in every yuga.
According to Indonesian Ramayana The Uttarakanda 64 his existence will end with the end of our Kaliyuga (according to Rigveda 5.87.4b and Mahabharata 3.189.33 this will take place when the constellation Orion - identical with Vishnu - will arrive its upper point of return in the course of the precession which will be the case in short time).