# Hanuman forgeting divine powers

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

In the ongoing TV serial, **Mahabali Hanuman**, it was shown that **Hanuman** forgot his **shaktis**(Powers) due to curse by Rishis when he went to Swarg Lok to bring back his mother. But, as far as I know, Hanuman was cursed by a Rishi to forget his divine powers while he made lives of Rishis miserable alongwith his friends. So, which story is authentic?

My question is: Which of the versions is authentic?? I am asking this question because in the TV serial, the whole incident is shown in a diffent context.

Comment: Well, it was the curses of sages that made Sri Hanuman forget his strength. This is the authentic reason as it is quoted in Valmiki Ramayana (Uttar Kand). You will find your answer here in a similar question (**Why did Lord Hanuman not help kill Vali**). I also posted screenshots of the excerpts. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/why-didnt-lord-hanuman-help-sugriva-to-kill-vali/9297#9297

Comment: Your question has answers here (**Why did Lord Hanuman forget that he has special powers?**). http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/why-did-lord-hanuman-forget-that-he-has-special-powers

Comment: I am asking whether the fact shown in the ongoing TV serial is not authentic....

Comment: Well, if that is what they show, then it is not authentic as we have Valmiki Ramayana by our side to prove that it was only due to the mischiefs of Sri Hanuman that the sages cursed him. Please have a look at Keshav's answer in link of my previous comment.

Comment: TV serials nowadays use a lot of their own stories just to create better TRPs  and to attract ignorant audiences. I think I also saw an incident in initial episodes of this TV serial where Garuda comes to meet Lord Krishna and Sudarshan Chakra (in human form) doesn't allow him to enter. They both had heated conversation. I think this was also a story plotted by production house.

Comment: @Jatin: Yes, I agree with you. But, I am pointing out the deviation of TV serials.

Comment: @Aby: Like you, I too have seen Hanuman eating the Sudarshan Chakra only in that TV serial.